# Alexa app drop in feature and contacts missing after upgrading iPhone

Tags: alexa, amazon-echo

I am missing the drop in feature and my Alexa contacts after upgrading my iPhone (7 plus to 8 plus).  Restarting the app does not help.  I know I am logged in and connected because I can see the history of commands on all of my devices and see that they are connected.

Comment: Unfortunately, Dan's answer didn't work on my Alexa android app. In case anybody else is also at a loss, I am at least able to use the drop in function by voice command: > Alexa drop in to XXXX's echo

Comment: Thank you! This has helped my just now. I had exact issue after upgrading to Iphone 11! Thank you!!!!!

Answer (score 6):

I just spoke with Amazon support and came up with a solution.  I had to logout of the Alexa app by going to the bottom of the settings section and signing out.  I then logged back in, selected the conversation bubble at the bottom of the screen (drop-in feature was still missing), selected the profile icon (person at top right), and finally selecting the conversation bubble at the bottom again.  That caused it to reappear along with all of my previous contacts.

Hope this helps someone.